# In Emacs, how can we apply the new indent style for our existing code?

Tags: emacs

Being read about [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), now I must change my current indent style from [Banner Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Banner_style), to [Allman Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style_.28bsd_in_Emacs.29). I've changed the indent style using c-set-style and choosing bsd. But, now how do I apply the new indent style?

That is, can emacs reformat my code, and apply this new coding stye?
How can I configure emacs to use this sytle to be my java default style.

Thank you.

Comment: Now I know there is Semantic package in emacs. I think that help me alot in coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indent-region to apply your indentation settings.  If you want to re-indent the whole buffer, mark-whole-buffer (C-x h) followed by indent-region (C-M-\) should do it.

EDIT:

If you want to automatically move the braces onto their own lines, as in the style you cite, you'll have to do some regexp replacements as well. The following might be a start:

```
(query-replace-regexp "^\\([^{}\n]+[^{} \t\n]+[^{}\n]*\\)\\([{}]\\)$" "\\1\n\\2")
```

This will take any { or } character that is the last character on a line and put it on its own line. It will ignore any {} characters that are the first character on their lines. You may need to follow this with:

```
(query-replace-regexp "^\\(\\s *[{}]\\)\\(.+\\)$" "\\1\n\\2")
```

This will take any {} characters that are first on their line and are followed by other characters, and insert a newline between the brace and the other characters.

Following this, my original suggestion of mark-whole-buffer and indent-region should correct the indentation.

EDIT 2: fixed the first regexp to account for leading whitespace

Comment: It didn't happen. The opening braces for a function definition can not printed on the next line( as in BSD style)

Comment: Ah, no, sorry, I guess it wouldn't. I don't think emacs indentation commands will alter anything other than the actual indentation, i.e., the leading whitespace on each line. You might need to use some creative regexp replacements to move the braces from one line to the next, then use mark-whole-buffer and indent-region to tidy up the actual indentation.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. But, I don't think I can do it with emacs. Some sort of code beautifier should do it :)

Comment: See my edits - they handled some simple test cases, maybe it's enough for your problem.

Comment: Where do I execute the code? Using M-X, and paste that? I've tried, but it doesn't work... or M-x, query-replace-regexp, and paste : "^\\([^{}\n]+[^{} \t\n]+[^{}\n]*\\)\\([{}]\\)$" "\\1\n\\2". It doesn't work either... thanks

Comment: No, the way I've written it you need to copy the full line (query-replace-regexp ... ), call eval-expression (which is bound to M-: ) and then paste the line in the minibuffer at the Eval: prompt.